# Docker error when I try to run Kong: nginx configuration is invalid

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, kong

I want to use Docker to run Kong with OIDC plugin in order to connect it with an external Keycloak server. The Kong container exits with code 1 because of a bad configuration of its nginx server. I have this **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3.8'
networks:
  kong-net:
services:
  kong:
    build: ./kong
    image: amilcar-backend/kong
    networks:
      - kong-net
    depends_on:
      - kong-db
    environment:
      KONG_DATABASE: postgres
      KONG_PG_HOST: kong-db
      KONG_PG_DATABASE: kong
      KONG_PG_PASSWORD: kong
      KONG_PG_USER: kong
      KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG: /dev/stdout
      KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG: /dev/stderr
      KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG: /dev/stdout
      KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG: /dev/stderr
      KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN: 0.0.0.0:8001
      KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS: postgres
      KONG_NGINX_PROXY_SET: '$session_secret amUgc8OpY3VyaKJIHGENldHRlIHJvdXRl'
      KONG_PLUGINS: oidc
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
      - '8001:8001'
  kong-migration:
    image: amilcar-backend/kong
    command: "kong migrations bootstrap"
    networks:
      - kong-net
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      KONG_PG_HOST: kong-db
      KONG_PG_DATABASE: kong
      KONG_PG_PASSWORD: kong
    depends_on:
      - kong-db
      - kong
  kong-db:
    image: 'postgres:12.6-alpine'
    container_name: 'kong-db'
    networks:
      - kong-net
    ports:
      - '5436:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: kong
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: kong
      POSTGRES_DB: kong
    volumes:
      - kong-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  db:
    image: 'postgres:12.6-alpine'
    container_name: 'db'
    ports:
      - '5434:5432'
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  postgres:
  kong-postgres:
```

And I have this Dockerfile in **./kong**:

```
FROM kong:latest
USER root
RUN luarocks install kong-oidc
USER kong
CMD ["kong", "docker-start"]
```

It's all good unless the Kong container, it throws this error:

```
kong_1 | Error: could not prepare Kong prefix at /usr/local/kong: nginx configuration is invalid (exit code 1):
kong_1 | nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "set" directive in /usr/local/kong/nginx-kong.conf:80
kong_1 | nginx: configuration file /usr/local/kong/nginx.conf test failed
```

I tried different solutions but this error follows me everywhere...

Comment: Well, what does line 80 of the nginx configuration look like?

Comment: It is a container so I don't know how to access to a view of the files

Comment: One option for seeing the generated file is `docker cp <container_name_or_id>:/usr/local/kong/nginx.conf nginx.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kong service:

```
KONG_NGINX_PROXY_SET: '$session_secret amUgc8OpY3VyaKJIHGENldHRlIHJvdXRl'
```

must be:

```
KONG_NGINX_PROXY_SET: '$$session_secret amUgc8OpY3VyaKJIHGENldHRlIHJvdXRl'
```